# Sufficient conditions for this function being constant

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued function for which, for every real $x$:

$$f(2x) = f(x)$$

Does this imply that $f$ is a constant function?

1. In general, the answer is **no**. For example, $f$ can be the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function) - 1 on the rational and 0 on the irrationals.
2. If $f$ is continuous at 0, then I think the answer is **yes**. PROOF: assume, by contradiction, that there are $x,y$ such that $f(x)>f(y)$. Then, by the condition on $f$, for every integer $n$: $f(x/2^n) > f(y/2^n)$. But this means that $f$ cannot be continuous at 0.
3. What is the answer if $f$ is continuous everywhere but not at 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your treatment of 1 and 2 seem correct to me. Regarding 3, consider that the value on $[1, 2]$ defines the value for the positive reals. So long as its continuous on that interval and has $f(1)=f(2)$ then its continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$. So, 3 is insufficient.